# Sliding windows along last axis of a 2D array to give a 3D array using NumPy strides

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stride

I am trying to use the function `as_strided` from `numpy.lib.stride_tricks` to extract sub series from a larger 2D array, but I struggled to find the right thing to write for the `strides` argument.

Let's say I have a matrix `m` which contains 5 1D array of length (`a=`)10. I want to extract sub 1D arrays of length (`b=`)4 for each 1D array in `m`.

```
import numpy
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

a, b = 10, 4
m = numpy.array([range(i,i+a) for i in range(5)])

# first try
sub_m = as_strided(m, shape=(m.shape[0], m.shape[1]-b+1, b))
print sub_m.shape # (5,7,4) which is what i expected
print sub_m[-1,-1,-1] # Some unexpected strange number: 8227625857902995061

# second try with strides argument
sub_m = as_strided(m, shape=(m.shape[0], m.shape[1]-b+1, b), strides=(m.itemize,m.itemize,m.itemize))
# gives error, see below
```

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'itemize'

As you can see I succeed to get the right shape for `sub_m` in my first try. However I can't find what to write in `strides=()`

For information:

```
m = [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13]]
```

Expected output:

```
sub_n = [
         [[0 1 2 3] [1 2 3 4] ... [5 6 7 8] [6 7 8 9]]
         [[1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5] ... [6 7 8 9] [7 8 9 10]]
         [[2 3 4 5] [3 4 5 6] ... [7 8 9 10] [8 9 10 11]]
         [[3 4 5 6] [4 5 6 7] ... [8 9 10 11] [9 10 11 12]]
         [[4 5 6 7] [5 6 7 8] ... [9 10 11 12] [10 11 12 13]]
        ]
```

*edit*: I have much more data, that's the reason why I want to use `as_strided` (efficiency)

Comment: What's the shape of the expected output?  Consider the input has shape (m,n) and you have a stride length of say `L`.

Comment: Expected output shape: (5,7,4) (m,n,L), with L = m-4+1

Comment: Maybe you mean (m,n-L+1,L)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You're right (the same as in the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
def strided_lastaxis(a, L):
    s0,s1 = a.strides
    m,n = a.shape
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(m,n-L+1,L), strides=(s0,s1,s1))
```

**Bit of explanation on strides for `as_strided` :**

We have 3D strides, that increments by one element along the last/third axis, so `s1` there for the last axis striding. The second axis strides by the same one element "distance", so `s1` for that too. For the first axis, the striding is same as the first axis stride length of the array, as we move on the next row, so `s0` there.

Sample run -

```
In [46]: a
Out[46]: 
array([[0, 5, 6, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 4, 8],
       [2, 1, 3, 7, 0, 3, 5, 4, 0, 1]])

In [47]: strided_lastaxis(a, L=4)
Out[47]: 
array([[[0, 5, 6, 2],
        [5, 6, 2, 3],
        [6, 2, 3, 6],
        [2, 3, 6, 7],
        [3, 6, 7, 1],
        [6, 7, 1, 4],
        [7, 1, 4, 8]],

       [[2, 1, 3, 7],
        [1, 3, 7, 0],
        [3, 7, 0, 3],
        [7, 0, 3, 5],
        [0, 3, 5, 4],
        [3, 5, 4, 0],
        [5, 4, 0, 1]]])
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. However I still don't understand what I should put in the last argument. Where does `(s0,s1,s1)` comes from? I would really appreciate if you can add more details so next time I don't have to ask :)

Comment: @Nuageux Heartfelt apologies Sir! Added comments.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation, it's not the first time that I'm fighting with this function, next time I think I won't! (PS: Why the sir?)