# Looking for an efficient way to reorganize a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a Dataframe structured like so...

```
       D           K         Factor        p
0   -0.483128   -1.240024  -1.214765   -1.002418
1   -0.692334   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304
2   -1.189383   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304
3   -1.691841   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304
4   -2.084926   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304
```

I'm trying to reorganize the data into a new structure where each row contains 'period' number of rows from the existing data.  Moves ahead one row in existing and the stacks the next 'period lines'.

the function so far:

```
def prepData(seq, period):
    newStacks = pd.DataFrame()
    for pos in range(0, len(seq) - (period+1), 1):
        chunk = (seq[pos:pos + period])
        stack = []
        for sliver in range(0, len(chunk), 1):
            piece = (chunk.iloc[sliver:])
            print(piece)
            stack.append(piece) 
        
        newStacks.append(chunk)

return newStacks
```

this obviously is not efficient and aside doesn't produce the desire structure.  The aim is to get a structure like below considering period = 3

```
0   -0.483128   -1.240024   -1.214765   -1.002418   -0.692334   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304 -1.189383  -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304
1   -0.692334   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304    -1.189383   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304 -1.691841  -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304
2   -1.189383   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304    -1.691841   -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304 -2.084926  -1.632132   1.562630    0.997304
```

AA Simple way to accomplish this  would be appreciated.

Comment: You want the result to be a dataframe or a numpy array or a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are all floats columns for improve performance use `strides` in numpy with reshape `3d array` to `2d` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306231/2901002 a bit changed
def strided_lastaxis(a, L):
    s0,s1 = a.strides
    m,n = a.shape
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(m-L+1,L,n), strides=(s0,s0,s1))

a = strided_lastaxis(df.to_numpy(), 3)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1))
print (df1)
         0         1         2         3         4         5        6   \
0 -0.483128 -1.240024 -1.214765 -1.002418 -0.692334 -1.632132  1.56263   
1 -0.692334 -1.632132  1.562630  0.997304 -1.189383 -1.632132  1.56263   
2 -1.189383 -1.632132  1.562630  0.997304 -1.691841 -1.632132  1.56263   

         7         8         9        10        11  
0  0.997304 -1.189383 -1.632132  1.56263  0.997304  
1  0.997304 -1.691841 -1.632132  1.56263  0.997304  
2  0.997304 -2.084926 -1.632132  1.56263  0.997304
```

Comment: you continue to amaze me with your deep knowledge in pandas/numpy/python. Thx for sharing this. Didn't know about strides.

Comment: @JoeFerndz - Honestly numpy is still hard to me, still learning. Pandas is better for me, because I  more coding with it, it means more experience.

Comment: Very Clever!  Thanks for this solution

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want to create a dataframe or a list. Here's the code to get you both.

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['D','K','Factor','p']
d = [[-0.483128,   -1.240024,  -1.214765,   -1.002418],
[-0.692334,   -1.632132,   1.562630,    0.997304],
[-1.189383,   -1.632132,   1.562630,    0.997304],
[-1.691841,   -1.632132,   1.562630,    0.997304],
[-2.084926,   -1.632132,   1.562630,    0.997304]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
print (df)

p = 3 #this is the period you wanted. I set it to 3
stack_list = []   #this will store the final stacked list
                  #note: don't use stack, its used by pandas to stack

for i in range(len(df)-p+1):  #iterating thru the dataframe
    # convert p rows to a list after you stack them
    chunk = df.loc[i:i+p-1].stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).tolist()

    stack_list.append(chunk)   #store chunk to stack_list


df1 = pd.DataFrame(stack_list)   #creating a dataframe as per your request

#printing both stack_list and dataframe

print (stack_list)
print (df1)
```

The output of this will be:

The original dataframe is:

```
          D         K    Factor         p
0 -0.483128 -1.240024 -1.214765 -1.002418
1 -0.692334 -1.632132  1.562630  0.997304
2 -1.189383 -1.632132  1.562630  0.997304
3 -1.691841 -1.632132  1.562630  0.997304
4 -2.084926 -1.632132  1.562630  0.997304
```

The stacked list is:

```
[[-0.483128, -1.240024, -1.214765, -1.002418, -0.692334, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304, -1.189383, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304], 
 [-0.692334, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304, -1.189383, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304, -1.691841, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304], 
 [-1.189383, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304, -1.691841, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304, -2.084926, -1.632132, 1.56263, 0.997304]]
```

The new dataframe that you wanted to get created is:

```
         0         1         2   ...        9        10        11
0 -0.483128 -1.240024 -1.214765  ... -1.632132  1.56263  0.997304
1 -0.692334 -1.632132  1.562630  ... -1.632132  1.56263  0.997304
2 -1.189383 -1.632132  1.562630  ... -1.632132  1.56263  0.997304
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Joe.  I upvoted your answers as it is a good solution.  I chose jezrael's solution for my implementation.